# characteristic function differentiation

Tags: probability-theory, derivatives, proof-verification, induction, characteristic-functions

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Then the characteristic function is:
$$
\varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \;\;\ \varphi(t):=i\int_\mathbb{R} e^{itx}d\mu(x)
$$

Prove with induction that, if $E(|X|^n)< \infty$, then $\varphi$ is $n$-times continuously differentiable and:
$$
\varphi^{(k)}(0)=i^{k}\int_\mathbb{R} x^{k}d\mu(x),\;\;\;\; k=0,1,2,3,\dots,n
$$

I have managed a proof for $k=1$, but im stuck with any values of $k\geq 2$.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Interchange integration and differentiation, i.e. use that $$\frac{d^k}{d^k t} \int e^{\imath \, t x} \, d\mu(x) = \int \frac{d^k}{d^k t} e^{\imath \, t x} \mu(dx).$$ (Here $\frac{d^k}{d^k t}$ denotes the $k$-th derivative with respect to $t$.)

---

**Remark:** It follows from the theorem on differentiation of parametrized integrals and the integrability condition $\int |x|^n \, d\mu < \infty$ that we are indeed allowed to interchange integration and differentiation. The theorem states that if we consider an integral of the form

$$V(t) := \int g(t,x) \, d\mu(x)$$

where $g(t,\cdot) \in L^1(\mu)$ for all $t$ and $|\partial_t g(t,x)| \leq w(x)$ for some integrable function $w \in L^1(\mu)$, then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} V(t) = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial t} g(t,x) \, d\mu(x).$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the hint! My actual problem is that when you write out the $\varphi^{(k+1)}(0)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\varphi^{(k)}(h)-\varphi^{(k)}(0)}{h}$, for $k=0$ the function is given $\varphi^{(0)}(h)$ i.e. $\varphi(t)$. 
So the trouble im having is getting $\varphi^{(k)}(h)$.
And when moving the limit inside the integral, we had to use the dominant convergence theorem.

Comment: @wombat Yes, in order to move the limit inside, we have to use some theorem (e.g. differentation of parametrized integrals). But since $\int |x|^n \, d\mu(x)<\infty$, it is not difficult to show that the integrability assumptions are satisfied. In fact, if we consider $$\int g(t,x) \, d\mu(x)$$, then we need $g(t,x) \in L^1$ and $|\partial_t g(t,x)| \leq w(x)$ for all $t,x$ in order to interchange differentiation and integration. In this case, $$g(t,x) := e^{\imath \, t x}$$ and $$|\partial_t g(t,x)| \leq |x| \in L^1(\mu).$$ A very similar argumentation applies to derivatives of higher order.