# Exchangeability of differentiation and integration to show a characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, derivatives, characteristic-functions

I am having a hard time to understand how the exchangeability of integration and differentiation is justified under $E[|X|^{k}]<\infty$ for a characteristic function in the context of showing $E[X^{k}]=i^{-k}\phi^{(k)}(0)$, where $\phi^{\left(k\right)}(0)$ is the k-th differentiation of $\phi$ with respect to $t = 0$.

I must use the following exchangeability to show this.

$$\frac{d^{k}}{dt^{k}}\int e^{itx}d\mu(x)=\int \frac{d^{k}}{dt^{k}}e^{itx}d\mu(x)$$

However, I am not sure how $E[|X|^{k}]<\infty$ is used to show the exchangeability.

I already saw [characteristic function differentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989203/characteristic-function-differentiation?newreg=4dd5dffb6cec4c4aaab60e07c27cdcee)

but it does not help me to understand the importance of a finite moment.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: $\int |\frac{d^k}{dt^k}e^{itx}|\mu(dx) = E(|X|^k)$, so $E(|X|^k) < \infty$ is a necessary condition for the result to even make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $\mathbb{E}[|X|^k]<\infty$ is necessary to guarantee the existence and finiteness of $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$. Also, it is used to **justify** that interchanging integration and differentiation is valid. (In general, you can't interchange the order of two limiting operators without extra assumptions.)

In doing so, the relevant theorem is as follows:

> **Theorem.** Let $\nu$ be a signed measure such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\nu(\mathrm{d}x)| < \infty$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x| |\nu(\mathrm{d}x)| < \infty$. Then
>
> $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx} \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} e^{itx} \, \nu(\mathrm{d}x). $$

Once this has been proved, we can inductively check that $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[|X|^k] < \infty$ implies

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}t^k} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-1}}{\mathrm{d}t^{k-1}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}e^{itx} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) \tag{Thm, $\nu = \mu$} \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-2}}{\mathrm{d}t^{k-2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} e^{itx} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) \tag{Thm, $\nu=x\mu$} \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-3}}{\mathrm{d}t^{k-3}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{d}t^3} e^{itx} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) \tag{Thm, $\nu=x^2\mu$} \\
&\qquad \vdots \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}t^k} e^{itx} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) \tag{Thm, $\nu=x^{k-1}\mu$}
\end{align*}

---

It remains to prove the theorem.

*Proof.* Write $\phi_{\mu}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ and $\psi_{\mu}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} ix e^{itx} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)$. Then for $h \neq 0$,

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{\phi_{\mu}(t+h) - \phi_{\mu}(t)}{h} - \psi_{\mu}(t) \right|
&= \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{0}^{1} ix (e^{ihxs} - 1) \, \mathrm{d}s \right) e^{itx} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) \right| \\
&\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{0}^{1} \left| e^{ihxs} - 1\right| \, \mathrm{d}s \right) |x| \, |\mu(\mathrm{d}x)|
\end{align*}

Since $x \mapsto \int_{0}^{1} \left| e^{ihxs} - 1\right| \, \mathrm{d}s$ is uniformly bounded by $2$ and tends to $0$ as $h \to 0$ pointwise, the above bound converges to $0$ as $h \to 0$ by the dominated convergence theorem. This proves that $\phi_{\mu}(t)$ is differentiable with $\phi_{\mu}'(t) = \psi_{\mu}(t)$ as desired.